# Store XML nodes in array

Tags: c#, .net

I have this below XML response . I need to store each node and its value in a array and the attach the array in the URL as querystring and redirect to a diferrent page . Please help

```
<responseId>76</responseId>
<status>SUCCESS</status>
<result>
    <reference_number>FA002900118</reference_number>
    <remitter_id>10023</remitter_id>
    <remitter_name>TEST SACCO</remitter_name>
    <beneficiary_id>9</beneficiary_id>
    <beneficiary_name>KENYA USA DIASPORA SACCO LTD</beneficiary_name>
    <trans_type>Account</trans_type>
    <destination_country>Kenya</destination_country>
    <source_currency>USD</source_currency>
    <source_transfer_amount>10.00</source_transfer_amount>
    <rate>83.4000</rate>
    <destination_currency>KES</destination_currency>
    <destination_amount>834.00</destination_amount>
    <commission>5.00</commission>
    <agent_fee>0.00</agent_fee>
    <hq_fee>0.00</hq_fee>
    <remitter_pay_amount>15.00</remitter_pay_amount>
    <agent_deduction>2.50</agent_deduction>
    <agent_to_pay_hq>12.50</agent_to_pay_hq>
    <delivery_date>2012-12-07 00:00:00-05</delivery_date>
    <payment_token>3954d4d87aa2926dbb6150658881ec4622b101b6</payment_token>
</result>
```

I have somehow reached to some code to get the output with some delimiter but still confused how to put the same in an array and paas it as querystring to next page

string str = "";

```
    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("D:/TempXml.Xml");
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        XmlNodeType nodeType = reader.NodeType;
        switch (nodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                str+= " Element - " + reader.Name + ";";
                if (reader.HasAttributes)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < reader.AttributeCount; i++)
                    {
                        reader.MoveToAttribute(i);
                        str+= "Attribute - " + reader.Name + reader.Value;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Text:
                str += " Value - " + reader.Value + ";";
                break;
        }
    }
    Label1.Text = str;
```

output

Element - response; Element - responseId; Value - 76; Element - status; Value - SUCCESS; Element - result; Element - reference_number; Value - FA002900118; Element - remitter_id; Value - 10023; Element - remitter_name; Value - TEST SACCO; Element - beneficiary_id; Value - 9; Element - beneficiary_name; Value - KENYA USA DIASPORA SACCO LTD; Element - trans_type; Value - Account; Element - destination_country; Value - Kenya; Element - source_currency; Value - USD; Element - source_transfer_amount; Value - 10.00; Element - rate; Value - 83.4000; Element - destination_currency; Value - KES; Element - destination_amount; Value - 834.00; Element - commission; Value - 5.00; Element - agent_fee; Value - 0.00; Element - hq_fee; Value - 0.00; Element - remitter_pay_amount; Value - 15.00; Element - agent_deduction; Value - 2.50; Element - agent_to_pay_hq; Value - 12.50; Element - delivery_date; Value - 2012-12-07 00:00:00-05; Element - payment_token; Value - 3954d4d87aa2926dbb6150658881ec4622b101b6;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use next code you can get `List` of `KeyValuePair`, where key is tag name and value is tag content text:

```
string responce = @"
<responce>
<responseId>76</responseId>
<status>SUCCESS</status>
<result>
<reference_number>FA002900118</reference_number>
<remitter_id>10023</remitter_id>
<remitter_name>TEST SACCO</remitter_name>
<beneficiary_id>9</beneficiary_id>
<beneficiary_name>KENYA USA DIASPORA SACCO LTD</beneficiary_name>
<trans_type>Account</trans_type>
<destination_country>Kenya</destination_country>
<source_currency>USD</source_currency>
<source_transfer_amount>10.00</source_transfer_amount>
<rate>83.4000</rate>
<destination_currency>KES</destination_currency>
<destination_amount>834.00</destination_amount>
<commission>5.00</commission>
<agent_fee>0.00</agent_fee>
<hq_fee>0.00</hq_fee>
<remitter_pay_amount>15.00</remitter_pay_amount>
<agent_deduction>2.50</agent_deduction>
<agent_to_pay_hq>12.50</agent_to_pay_hq>
<delivery_date>2012-12-07 00:00:00-05</delivery_date>
<payment_token>3954d4d87aa2926dbb6150658881ec4622b101b6</payment_token>
</result>
</responce>";

        StringReader reader=new StringReader(responce);

        XElement root = XElement.Load(reader);

        XElement resultNode = (XElement)root.Nodes().Single(node => ((XElement)node).Name == "result");

        IList<KeyValuePair<string, string>> result = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

        foreach(XElement item in resultNode.Nodes())
        {
            KeyValuePair<string, string> resultItem = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(item.Name.ToString(), item.Value);
            result.Add(resultItem);
        }
```

i think you can create query string form list. 
For redirect to other page in ASP.NET you can use `HttpResponce.Redirect` (more info  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9dwyts4.aspx)

Comment: This makes sense .. just a request how can i take the string responce  from file

Comment: You can use XDocument.Load(filePath) for getting xml from file. But file must contains valid xml for that